# CSS: How to use Transform property on a bootstrap grid class

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, css, css-transitions

I am trying to use the `transform` property in CSS3 on a bootstrap a `class="col-sm-4"` div, the problem is I don't have a width or a height specified, and so the transform property is not working. Here is the current code

Bootstrap HTML

```
<div class="col-sm-4" class="threed">
    <div class="services-box">
        <img src="img/food-pic1.png" alt="food delivery" width="40%" height="30%">
        <h4> Food Delivery<hr></h4>
        <p> We delivery food straight to your doorstep. Now you don't have to worry about anything! </p>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.row {
   margin-left: 0%;
}
```

Property I want to add (but doesn't work)

```
.col-sm-4:hover {
   box-shadow: 1px 1px #53a7ea,
               2px 2px #53a7ea,
               3px 3px #53a7ea;
   -webkit-transform: translateX(-3px);
   transform: translateX(-3px);
}
```

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't apply `css` to bootstrap classes if you do so, the whole bootstrap classes in your website will get that `css`, so i will recommend using a **custom class** or to apply it on `.col-sm-4` you should specify its parent to avoid applying css to whole website where `col-sm-4` is used.

Here is a **snippet**

```css
.threed{
 -webkit-transform: translateX(0);
   transform: translateX(0);
-webkit-transition:all 0.3s ease;
  transition:all 0.3s ease;
}

.threed:hover {
   box-shadow: 1px 1px #53a7ea,
               2px 2px #53a7ea,
               3px 3px #53a7ea;
   -webkit-transform: translateX(3px);
   transform: translateX(3px);
}
```

```html
<div class="col-sm-4 threed">
    <div class="services-box">
        <img src="img/food-pic1.png" alt="food delivery" width="40%" height="30%">
        <h4> Food Delivery<hr></h4>
        <p> We delivery food straight to your doorstep. Now you don't have to worry about anything! </p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

I fixed it by defining `.col-sm-4` as

```
 .col-sm-4 {
     ...;
     transition: all .5s;
     box-shadow: 0px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0),
                 0px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0),
                 0px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0);
 }
```

Then the hover effect should fade in and out.  You can target solely `box-shadow` instead of `all` for `transition`, and of course change the time too.

Transition requires a default template to change from, and doesn't assume a non-visible css properties for the object in question.